# Outlook and Teams - Reset Free/Busy status every day

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams

I sometimes set my Outlook status as "Busy" or "Away" while trying to focus without interruptions.  The problem is the next day I forget to reset the status so it goes back to reading from my calendar.  I'm wondering if there is a way to tell Outlook to reset my status every morning.  I typically hibernate my computer every night so Outlook isn't launched freshed each morning.

I'm ok with a VBA, batch file, or AutoHotkey solution so long as it can be automated.  If I have to manually run something every day that I may as well remember to reset the status.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I honestly did do some googling before posting the question.  In taking the screenshot above from Teams I noticed the **Duration** menu option which I had always ignored in the past.  I just checked it out and it does exactly what I'm looking for.

[image]

It even lets me pick when I want the reset to happen.

[image]

I hope you find this as useful as I did.

Comment: Good sharing! It's helpful.